# RMySQL dbWriteTable to a table with a MySQL reserved word as name

Tags: r, rmysql

I am having trouble with the dbWriteTable command from the RMySQL package. I have to append records to a table name which is called 'order', a reserved word in MySQL.

```
dbWriteTable(connection, "`order`", df, append = T)
```

Give as error:

> Warning message:
>   In mysqlWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) :
>    could not create table: aborting mysqlWriteTable

Other queries like SELECT work fine as long as I put order between back ticks.

Any ideas how the execute the dbWriteTable command? And renaming the table is unfortunately no option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write it as a qualified name, example: mydb.order (without backticks).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. It works for table names that aren't reserved bij MySQL.

Comment: do you have the same message?

Comment: Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: Table 'order' already exists) I used 'append = T'

Comment: row.names = F doesn't work either. I created a workaround. I created made a copy of the ORDER table and named this table temp_ORDER. And now I can update the ORDER tables with the values from the temp_ORDER table via the dbSendQuery command. So it seems only the dbWriteTable command creates errors with a reserved name as table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
dbWriteTable(connection, "`order`", df, append = 1)
```